# How remove auto generated <p> tag from WordPress editor that generate before <iframe> tag

Tags: wordpress

I convert an HTML template to a WordPress theme. I use a custom field plugin to do this, but when I try to lode a map in the `<iframe>` tag the the output looks like `<p><iframe {code..}></iframe></p>`. How to remove this `p` tag that is automatically generated?

I used the following code in `functions.php` but it did not fix the problem:

```
<?php 

remove_filter('term_description','wpautop');    
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Login to WordPress Dashboard
2.Go to Appearance > Editor
3.Select Theme Functions (functions.php) file.
4.Add the following function and click update changes.

```
// Remove P Tags Around Images
function filter_ptags_on_images($content)`{return preg_replace('/<p>\s*(<a .*>)?\s*(<img .* \/>)\s*(<\/a>)?\s*<\/p>/iU', '\1\2\3', $content);}
add_filter('the_content', 'filter_ptags_on_images');`
```

That’s all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Toggle wpautop](https://wordpress.org/plugins/toggle-wpautop/)  plugin for that.

This may be  very helpful for you.
Thanks

Comment: Thank you for response for my post @Mehul soni but i don't want to use any plugin.thank you

Answer (score 0):

Add following code in wp-config.php file:

```
define('WPCF7_AUTOP', false );
```